# Inserting a ZonedDateTime value to Oracle Timestamp With Timezone Column With JPA

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

In my SpringBoot project, I am trying to insert a `ZonedDateTime` value to an Oracle database where the column type is specified as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`. When I do that, the inserted value gets converted to the JVM timezone and gets inserted. However, what I expect is to insert the value in `ZonedDateTime` property as it is.

For example, if the `ZonedDateTime` value is set to `2020-05-16T12:12:24+02:30[US/Denver]`, then I expect to write to DB the same value and read from DB the same value. Is there any way I can do this with Hibernate and JPA

```
@Entity
class MyEntity{
   ZonedDateTime myDateTimeWithTimeZone;
} 

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>
{
}
```

This is how i am going to use it,

```
MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
myEntity.setMyDateTimeWithTimeZone(ZoneDateTime.now('US/Denver')) // This timezone can be anything depending on userInput
myRepository.save(myEntity);
```

Comment: how are you making the insert ? `timestamp with time zone` by default when no zone is specified gets the value of the session at client side.

Comment: I have updated my question with the usage